# Heap size of JVM in Android

Tags: java, android

for a PC, the default heap size for Java is 258 MB. what is the default heap size allocated to an Android application, say an activity starts and its created, how much memory does it get? I was curious since, phone has a limited memory space, would Google have decided a default memory allocation.

Comment: The default size isn't exactly 128MiB; it depends a lot on your architecture, your OS and probably other factors.

Comment: Here it says 128 MB, please see the 4th point under 10 points about...http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html#comment-form

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned 258 MB.

Comment: Android doesn't actually use JVM. It has Dalvik (DVM).

Comment: That article is incorrect for the given point, esp given that it doesn't point to any authoritative source. As as advice, you should be really careful reading stuff on the internet which is not supplemented by "official docs/links". :-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I was proven wrong my information was out of date. Its device dependant.
G1 - 16mb
Xoom - 48mb

Comment: Check out the videos about memory management from Google's 2011 I/O conference.  It depends on the android version, screen size, max memory, and if the application is requesting largeheap.  It has an upper bound of 256mb i believe, for tablet-sized screens and largeheap requested