# What is the maximum size of HTTP Post method in android

Tags: android, http, post, size, max

What is the maximum size of android Post method? When I am getting responses from server, parts of the message are missing. I think it may have reached the maximum size of post method.
If there is no limit for post method, did I need to change my server specification for this?

Comment: It seems to be browser based, and based on the server's configuration. I don't think (theoretically) there is a limit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I used HttpPost and the response got from server but a part of data missed because of their very big size. That's why I used an other way :  HttpURLConnection with OuputStream to send request to the server and BufferedReader/InputStream to get responses.

```
    HttpURLConnection my_httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://integrator-ut.vegaconnection.com/Authentication.svc?wsdl").openConnection();
    my_httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    my_httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
    my_httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    my_httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");



   OutputStream my_outPutStream = this.my_httpConnection.getOutputStream();
   Writer my_writer = new OutputStreamWriter(my_outPutStream);
   my_writer.write(YOUR_REQUEST); //YOUR_REQUEST is a String
   my_writer.flush();
   my_writer.close();           

   BufferedReader my_bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.my_httpConnection.getInputStream()));
    char[] buffer = new char[10000];
    int nbCharRead=0;
    try
    {
        while((nbCharRead = my_bufferReader.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1)
        {
             /* Your treatement : saving on a file/arraylist/etc

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically there isn't a limit. The POST response size is limited to Java VM Heap size [which is device independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479738/heap-size-of-jvm-in-android). It is probably more than your post response consumes.

How do you verify that part of your response is missing? If you print it out with LogCat or view it in debug mode, then you can see only the start of the message ending with three dots (all of the message is there, it isn't just displayed to you).